# Why is my validation set empty (Matlab-patternnet)?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm using simple demo code on custom input data.
I get weird problem, where my validation set is empty and only performance on test set is monitored (perhaps is the second problem consequence of the first one).

```
>> size(x)

ans =

    25   764

>> size(t)

ans =

     7   764

 trainFcn = 'trainbr';  % Scaled conjugate gradient backpropagation.

% Create a Pattern Recognition Network
hiddenLayerSize = 100;
net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize, trainFcn);

% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 60/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 20/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 20/100;

% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,x,t);

>> tr

tr = 

  struct with fields:
    
   divideFcn: 'dividerand'
  divideMode: 'sample'
 divideParam: [1×1 struct]
    trainInd: [1×611 double]
      valInd: []
     testInd: [1×153 double]
    
   best_perf: 0.0015
  best_vperf: NaN
  best_tperf: 0.0942
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is method dependent.. Other method (scg) has validation non-empty...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).